# How can I update my laravel composer manually?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, shared-hosting

I have installed laravel on my shared hosting service which works fine. I had previously installed Image intervention on my xammp local server through composer.. How do I use this package on my remote server?

Comment: if you are using windows then install putty and then ssh into the project and then install the package using the same command

Comment: putty isnt working on my windows 10

Comment: putty works on windows 10 as I use windows 10

Comment: please specify the versions of Laravel on both servers; provide more details on how you installed the package on you local server and what prevents you from doing the same on the shared hosting. This way, it will be easier for others to help you. Best regards

Comment: i get this error "network error: connection refused"

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

In `composer.json` add this line in `"require":` as

> "intervention/image": "^2.3"

and fire command in SSH window as `composer update`

Comment: there r no ssh window on my cpanel